# how split lines and get the pattern in lua?

Tags: split, lua, lua-patterns

I need in function,which do splitting of lines in lua. As i know,for splittings of lines by sep in lua i can use gmatch function,but i want to get sep in table to. For example,if i use pattern `%s*` and line `1 2  3 4`, I expect getting table like:`{1, ,2,  ,3, ,4}`,i.e size of table must be seven. Thanks very much everybody for the help.

Comment: `local s="1 2  3 4"; for w in s:gsub("%S+", "\0%0\0"):gmatch"%Z+" do print(w) end`

Comment: And this will works for any separator?